# Is the ASP.NET .ASPXAUTH cookie value always the same for a given user?

Tags: asp.net

Is the ASP.NET **.ASPXAUTH** cookie value always the same for a given user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not be.  The value contains a forms authentication ticket which has several values, some of which (like the expiration) will change every time the cookie is created, and *could* change on every request (if you have sliding expiration enabled.). If you enable encryption, (which you should!) even two identical plaintext tickets would result in two different encrypted cookie values.